# Save session Python to a Variable like session in C#

Tags: python, django

I want to use session to make cart feature in Python like ASP.NET :

```
Session["UserName"] = collection.Get("user_name");
```

How could i do ? or can you give me keyword to research this. thanks

Comment: You can use django session. Check details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Django was mentioned, and it's great if you design your platform around it. However, if you're looking to use some other framework, you could could use Redis.

As per their site (https://redis.io/):

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure
>   store, used as a database, cache and message broker. It supports data
>   structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with
>   range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with
>   radius queries. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU
>   eviction, transactions and different levels of on-disk persistence

With a Flask Session:

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/